# Minecraft Functions in Craftbukkit server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

I have a craftbukkit server running 1.12.1 with multiverse but cannot to get the new minecraft functions working.

From the root of the server I have a directory `/flat_world/data/functions/Hello` with file `Hi.mcfunction` 
with this content:

```
give @p minecraft:apple
```

On the server I go to flat_world and try:

```
/function hello:hi
```

But I get unknown function, the same file on a vanilla install of Minecraft running locally works fine. Is there something I need to do on the server version?

Comment: I created a craftbukkit 1.12.1 server with multiverse.  I added the same function file in the same directory.  The function is running properly with your command on my test server.  I did not create any other worlds though.  Have you attempted to put the function files into another world's function directory?

Comment: So that is really strange, I wonder if it was directory privileges on the server. I tried in another world and it works so I then deleted the folder from flat_world and copied in the second test everything worked fine. Thanks for the assistance